# Navigation Drawer fragment issue fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, android-developer-api

Hi so i tried to make a Navigation drawer in a sample project which i use fragments and code works in "FRAGMENTS" but by the time i use the code in my THESIS project which i use "ACTIVITY" instead of fragments... the code wont work... i hope u help me with this here is the code

```
package org.intercode.triviaquiz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Navigation extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
NavigationView navigationView = null;
Toolbar toolbar = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
    //Set the fragment initially
    //Set the fragment initially
    Main fragment = new Main();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
         Main fragment = new Main();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
         Quiz fragment = new Quiz();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the red line comes from 
fragment

```
 Main fragment = new Main();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

in here to be exact

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
```

the fragment after fragment_container has a redline... i believe the problem is because what i want to open when the app run is not a fragment the problem is i dont have idea what to replace it please help me guys its for my thesis :P

Comment: please check whether ur Main Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment or Not..!

Comment: Or check fragment_container id is present on  activity_navigation layout?

Comment: if you using AppCompatActivity then use getFragmentManager() instead for getSupportFragmentManager() from support v4.

Comment: Ya im using appcompact activity

Comment: I put getFrameManager() and fragment and whole android.support.v4 line have red underline now

Comment: it says

wrong 2nd argument type. Found  'org.intercode.triviaquiz.Main',required 'android.support.v4.fragment'
replace (int, android.support.v4.app.fragment) in fragmenttransaction cannot be applied
to int, org.intercode.triviaquiz.main

Comment: How can i  implement fragment in my main? if i already have appcompactactivity